# how to get size of directories quickly?

Tags: shell, unix

i am trying to get  the size of directories present in the some folder (below is given way i am using ) but  it takes lot of time when size is large.Can any one suggets me  easy and fast way?

```
for a in `ls`; do du -ch ${a} | grep  total ; echo ${a}; done
```

Comment: This won't speed it up much, but just `du -ch *` fixes a few ugly warts, including the problematic [`ls` in backticks](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls).

Answer (score 0):

du - estimate file space usage

du -sh and foldername

```
         du -sh .
```

It fastly given the current directory space

Comment: well i tried this timing are:-

real    10m54.781s

user    0m2.635s
sys     0m20.265s

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the size of many directories is usually slow. The more files you have the slower it gets. If your disk has some faults on it, that can significantly slow down the process too, and you would see disk I/O errors in your system log.

One flaw of your script that makes things even slower is grepping for total. Instead of `-c` flag you want to use the `-s` flag, which prints only the total. In fact, this line is equivalent to your script with clearer output:

```
du -sh *
```

PS: *Never* do `` for a in `ls` ``. This is much better: `for a in *`